# Can I assign values into a drop down list using razor manually?

Tags: vb.net, html.dropdownlistfor

Using vb.net, I want to do something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.Distance, (value1, value2, value3))
```

And just manually plug those three values in.  Seems like there should be an easy way to do this all in my html

Edit: Answer:

```
 @Code
  Dim listItems As New List(Of ListItem)
   listItems.Add(New ListItem("nameAsString", "valueAsString"))
   listItems.Add(New ListItem("nameAsString2", "valueAsString2"))
   listItems.Add(New ListItem("nameAsString3", "valueAsString3"))
  End Code

 @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.Distance, New SelectList(listItems))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work's just fine for me...

```
 @Code
  Dim listItems As New List(Of ListItem)
  listItems.Add(New ListItem("Just a Test", "0"))
  listItems.Add(New ListItem("Just a Test 2", "1"))
  listItems.Add(New ListItem("Just a Test 3", "2"))
 End Code

 @Html.DropDownList("TestList", New SelectList(listItems))
```

Comment: This is a great way to create this list.  But I do want to use DropDownListFor, not just drop down, in order to pass the selected value of the list into model.Distance